Moment on manifold, no dependence on Lagrangian anymore?
I am a bit confused about the mathematics of classical mechanics. When working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the generalized momentum is defined as the derivative of the Lagrangian with respect to the velocity but on a manifold, the generalized momentum seems to be defined as the basis of the cotangent space with no dependence anymore on the Lagrangian. How can this be?

Notice that if $$p_i=\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$$
of the lagrangian $\mathscr{L}\equiv \mathscr{L}(q_i,\dot{q_i})$, then the $p_i$ are the coordinates of the diferential of the functions $L_{q_i}(\dot{q_i}):=\mathscr{L}(q_i,\dot{q_i})$, in the standard basis $d\dot{q_i}$, $$p=dL= \sum_{1}^{n} \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}d\dot{q_i}$$ This means that even in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ the generalized momentum is best understood as living in its cotangent space, at every point $(\dot{q_1},\dot{q_2},...)$. The phase space would then be its cotagent bundle, which in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $T^* \mathbb{R}^n\cong \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$.
That is the reason why in more general treatments of classical mechanics, where instead of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for coordinate space we have a differentiable manifold, the phase space is defined as its cotagent bundle and the momentum as living in the cotagent space. Here, the Lagrangian dependence has disappeared because the partial derivative has lost its meaning.
About conjugate momenta in the manifold view of classical mechanics:
When the phase space is the cotangent bundle of some general differentiable manifold $Q$, the partial derivative $\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$, for $\mathscr{L}: TQ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, has no meaning because a manifold has no linear structure in general. The best we could do is to employ bundle coordinates $(q_i,v_i)$, but in this case $$p_i=\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial v_i}:=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\mathscr{L}\circ v_i^{-1}(x)  \right)$$ which we denote by the same symbol usually but is of a different meaning. This is all however for Lagrangian systems.
For Hamiltonian systems, the preferred approach is simply to choose suitable bundle coordinates without referring to the observables of the system (like the Hamiltonian). Recall that a Hamiltonian system is a pair $(T^*Q,\omega, H)$, where $\omega$ is the so called symplectic form. Although this form differs from the standard euclidean symplectic form $dq^j \wedge dp_j$ (summation convention used), there exists always an open neighbourhood and local coordinates $(q_i,p_i)$ in which the form assumes this standard expression (in the neighbourhood). Such coordinates are called canonical but must be employed only locally. Moreover the q's and the p's are interchangeable and as such regarding the p's as describing momenta is ill advised (even though we nevertheless refer to them as generalized momenta). In summary, the general stance is to choose a chart for $Q$ and take the induced bundle chart on $T^*Q$ as our momentum (which ammounts to choosing a random basis of the cotagent spaces), where for practical purposes we choose to employ canonical coordinates so that the symplectic form has a more tractable description.
Finally, there is an additional situation where our description of momenta on a manifold has more similarities with the usual description of conjugate momenta. This situation is that of the addition of a field. In this case we do not include the field in the Hamiltonian but instead describe the field as "deforming the symplectic structure", that is we  consider the Hamiltonian system $(T^*Q,\omega_F, H)$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian in the absence of the field and $\omega_F:= \omega_0+\pi^* F$, where $\omega_0$ is likewise the symplectic structure in the absence of the field, which is modelled by a closed two-form $F$ on $Q$, and $\pi$ is the canonical projection of the cotangent bundle. Just like the previous case, this new symplectic form $\omega_F$ is not the standard one, but one can bring it to this form locally by a suitable choice of coordinates. One can show that (seeing as locally $F=dA$ for some one-form $A$) these new deformed canonical coordinates can be obtained by the flat canonical ones by $$\begin{align} \tilde{q}_i=q_i \hspace{1cm} \tilde{p}_i=p_i-\pi^*A_i \end{align}$$ You can draw close analogy with the conjugate momenta as they're usually defined, conceptualizing $A$ as the electromagnetic potential and $F$ as its field strength.

thank you for answering. "Here, the Lagrangian dependence has disappeared because the partial derivative has lost its meaning" could you explain in more detail, this is the heart of my question.

@edamondo just added an edit, please tell me if anything is unclear

Given a Lagrangian $L:TQ\to \mathbb{R}$, we define a map $\mathbb{F}L:TQ\to T^*Q$ (sometimes called the Legendre transform) mapping fibres to fibres, where for $v_q, w_q\in T_qQ$
$$
\langle\mathbb{F}L(v_q),w_q\rangle := \frac{d}{dt}\Bigg\vert_{t=0}L(v_q+tw_q),
$$
or in local coordinates
$$
\mathbb{F}L(v_q) = \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}(v_q)\,dq^i.
$$
So here, $p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial\dot{q}^i}(v_q)$ define the coordinates of the momentum in the fibre $T^*_qQ$ corresponding to $v_q\in T_qQ$.
In favorable circumstances, $\mathbb{F}L$ will define an isomorphism between fibres $T_qQ$ and $T_q^*Q$ for all $q\in Q$, and in this case we say that the Lagrangian $L$ is hyperregular. A weaker version of this is that $\mathbb{F}L$ is locally invertible, which follows if the matrix of $\left[\frac{\partial^2 L}{\partial\dot{q}^i\partial\dot{q}^j}\right]$ is non-degenerate. Typically physical Lagrangians are quadratic in $\dot{q}$, and satisfy this property.
$T^*Q$ has an intrinsic symplectic structure $\omega = \sum_{i=1}^n dq^i\wedge dp_i$. $TQ$ doesn't, but can be assigned one if a hyperregular Lagrangian $L$ is given, via
$$
\omega_L:=(\mathbb{F}L)^*\omega.
$$
In local coordinates, this is
$$
\omega_L = \sum_{i=1}^n dq^i\wedge d\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}^i}\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial\dot{q}^i\partial \dot{q}^j}dq^i\wedge d\dot{q}^j+\frac{\partial^2L}{\partial\dot{q}^i\partial q^j}dq^i\wedge dq^j\right)
$$
